# Is this improper English?

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english

I was just looking to write articles about freelancing and found one forum where I told about my interest to write articles for their site,  I wrote to the author :

> I have been working as freelance since last 5 years. I am really interested to write and submit articles about freelancing. How can I do it here? Is there any option like Guest Post?

And after read above, author said :

> your English is not yet up to snuff… not yet good enough

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my lines above? Also, how can I improve those lines in perfect English?

Comment: I have been working as a freelance for the last 5 years. I am really interested about writing and submitting articles about freelancing. How can I do it here? Is there any option like Guest Post?

Comment: @RK01 - Thank you so much , can you just tell me why I should not use `Since` in first line , as you used `for`.

Comment: You  could keep the since, but following it, you would need to put when you started freelancing like : "since 5 years ago".

Comment: @RK01, your version isn't quite right yet.  it's *"freelancer"*, not "freelance", and it should be *"I am very interested in writing..."* , not "interested about writing".

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is really just proofreading, which is off topic here. You do have multiple errors in your writing.

Comment: A lot of classical mistakes... _Since_ doesn't mean what you think it means. You mean _for_. Articles are important in English, you can't leave them out at will. You're interested in doing something, not to do something. Your last sentence is hard to understand. I am guessing you mean to ask if there is any possibility to act as a guest poster.

Comment: @Catija - No problem , Actually I feel only this is place where I could get satisfied answer...:)

Comment: @oerkelens - Yes last sentence meaning is exactly what you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several grammatical errors in your message.

Moving some things around and correcting your grammar would look like:

> I have been working as a freelance writer for the last five years. I am really interesting in writing and submitting articles for your site. Is there a Guest Post option or some other way for me to contribute?